# How to remove Arraylist values after clicking on button

Tags: java, arraylist

I need your assistant and help in checking the arraylist which is available in the below method and at the beginning to clear or to remove the available data in the arraylist. The code is shown below:

```
List < BDetails > dataList = new ArrayList < BDetails > ();

public void Search() throws SQLException {

    try {
        while (result.next()) {

            BDetails cert = new BDetails();

            fromDT = result.getString("ECW_FROM_PERIOD");
            toDT = result.getString("ECW_TO_PERIOD");

            cert.setFromDate(fromDT);
            cert.setToDate(toDT);

            cert.setSeqNo(result.getString("ECW_REQ_SRL_NO"));
            //store all data into a List
            dataList.add(cert);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.print(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the clear() method of the list if you want to clear the arraylist. You can get more information in the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: yes I implemented the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood your question.
If you want to fully clear the list, you could use the function `clear()`.

See the documentation below:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

To remove a specific object from that list, lets say a `cert`, just use the function `remove(Object o)`, so in that case it would be `dataList.remove(cert)`

Comment: Do you mean that at the beginning I can use the code : cert.clear();

Comment: Because of the line `dataList.add(cert);` in your code, i assume you want to add the object `cert` to the list `dataList`. So if you want to remove that specific `cert` object, you could call `dataList.remove(cert)`